# T-SQL Convert Arithmetic Formula into its Components

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Problem Statement:
I have a Formula column that has the arithmetic operation in it. I want to extract the variable names from the formula, and delimit the variables with a comma and create a New Column "Formula Components"

```
The variable names follow the particular pattern - '%[^A-Za-z,_0-9 ]%'
```

However, I also want to keep the "Square Brackets" if they are to appear in the formula.

To Illustrate,

**Input Data:**

```
ID    |    Formula
------|-------------------------------------------
1     |    ([x1] + [x2]) / 100
2     |    ([y1] - [x2]) * 100 
3     |    z1 - z3 
4     |    [z4] % z3 
5     |    ((x1 * 2) + ((y1 + 2)/[x1])*[z3])/100
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID    |    Formula                                |   FormulaComponents
------|------------------------------------------ |-----------------
1     |   ([x1] + [x2]) / 100                     |  [x1],[x2]
2     |   ([y1] - [x2]) * 100                     |  [y1],[x2]
3     |   z1 - z3                                 |  [z1],[z3]
4     |   [z4] % z3                               |  [z4],[z3]
5     |   ((x1 * 2) + ((y1 + 2)/[x1])*[z3])/100   |  [x1],[y1],[z3]
```

As you can see above,

- Row 1. The Formula column consists of two variable, so the Formula
  components are [x1],[x2]
- Row 5. **Note that x1 appears two times in the formula; Once as x1
  and once as [x1]. In this case, I only want to keep only [x1] once. [x1] could appear N number of
  times in the Formula Column, but should appear only once in the FormulaComponents Column**

P.S.: *The Order of the variables appearing in the "FormulaComponents" column does not matter. So for example, in Row 5, the order can be [y1], [z3], [x1] OR [z3],[x1],[y1] and so on*

To summarize: I want to write a SELECT statement in T-SQL that will create this new column.

Comment: SQL Server has no inbuilt support for REGEX. I personally suggest looking into CLR Regex functions if you *must* do this in SQL, however, a language that natively supports it would be far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string using `string_split()` and then carefully reaggregate the results:

```
select *
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg('[' + value + ']', ',') as components
      from (select distinct replace(replace(value, '[', ''), ']', '') as value
            from string_split(replace(replace(replace(replace(t.formula, '(', ' '), ')', ' '), '*', ' '), '/', ' '), ' ') s
            where value like '[[a-z]%'
           ) s
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=913e261ea3c05d5797a9664e5dcac8bb) is a db<>fiddle.

This is made harder than necessary because your formulas do not have a canonical format.  It would be simpler if all variables were surrounded by square braces.  Or if all operators were surrounded by spaces.

EDIT:

SQL Server 2016 has `string_split()` but not `string_agg()`.  That fan be replaced with XML "stuff":

You can split the string using `string_split()` and then carefully reaggregate the results:

```
select *
from t cross apply
     (select stuff( (select distinct ',[' + value + ']'
                     from (select distinct replace(replace(value, '[', ''), ']', '') as value
                           from string_split(replace(replace(replace(replace(t.formula, '(', ' '), ')', ' '), '*', ' '), '/', ' '), ' ') s
                           where value like '[[a-z]%'
                          ) t
                     order by 1
                     for xml path ('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') as components
     ) s;
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the solution. However, I'm facing an error due to a version issue in ssms. I currently have Sql-server 2016 installed and it does not support the string_agg function. It would be great if you could provide an alternative solution to this. Extremely sorry for the trouble. I cannot upvote your comment as my reputation is 13 (under 15).

Comment: Hello - Thank you so so much for the updated Solution. I am trying to run it in the fiddle, but am getting an error. I am probably missing something obvious here.

Comment: @NeelDeorukhkar . . . I fixed the answer and the fiddle.